# NumberPicker inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, numberpicker

Lets say I have a ScrollView of LinearLayout (vertical) with a NumberPicker inside. In addition the LinearLayout does contain enough widgets so it scrolls.

Below is a sample XML code fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Some widgets here so it scrolls -->

    <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/npSec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On Android 4.1.2 (Galaxy S3) it works great... You scroll the the layout and once scroll the NumberPicker - only the NumberPicker scrolls.

On the other hand, on Android 4.0.x the layout scrolls well, BUT when the NumberPicker tries to be scrolled it does something awkward like scroll half value and stop between the value; from there - only the LinearLayout get scrolled and the NumberPicker is stuck.

This guy asked the exactly the same question and didn't get any answer: [NumberPicker on ScrollView doesn't scroll on Android 4.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823049/numberpicker-on-scrollview-doesnt-scroll-on-android-4-0-4)

[How disable ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102864/how-disable-scrollview) - This one won't do the job because both ScrollView and NumberPicker are vertical

I will really appreciate any good solution, or direction...
Thank you in advance,
Mark.

Comment: have you solved it since then? I am facing the same exact issue right now

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, still...

This works for me:

```
numberPicker.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && v.getParent() != null) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.performClick();
            }

            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```